# Multipart Request with MultipartFile as Optional Field - Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-upload, multipartform-data

I am using Spring MVC on a J2EE Web application.
I have created a method that bounds the request body to a model like the above

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public AModel createEntity(@Valid @ModelAttribute MyInsertForm myInsertForm) {
    // coding..
}
```

Everything are working great and when i include a property of type MultipartFile in the MyEntityForm, then i have to make the request with content type "multipart/form-data".
Also, everything are working great with this scenario too.

The problem i am facing is that i would like to have the MultipartFile property as optional.
When a client request include a file my method works great but when a client request does not include a file spring throws a

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: Stream ended unexpectedly

Is there any way to solve this issue without creating two methods on my controller (one with a MultipartFile and another without)?

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue and just adding the `required=false` worked for me; because, I don't send a file all the time. Please find the sample code below,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public AModel createEntity(@Valid @ModelAttribute MyInsertForm myInsertForm, @RequestParam(value ="file", required=false) MultipartFile file) {
    // coding..
}
```

Comment: do you know how to implement the same for a @PutMapping ?

Comment: @GabrielBrito If you want this for a form with a file, I think it's not possible to use PUT: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20388705/1084813

Answer (score 3):

Give a try by adding

```
(required=false)
```

to multipart property in method signature.

Answer (score -1):

When you wish to send one or more files using HTTP, you have to use multipart request. This means that the body of the request will be like the above,

> -----------------------------9051914041544843365972754266
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text"
>
> text default
>   -----------------------------9051914041544843365972754266
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="a.txt"
>   Content-Type: text/plain
>
> Content of a.txt.
>
> -----------------------------9051914041544843365972754266
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file2"; filename="a.html"
>   Content-Type: text/html

When you wish to send only data (and not files) you can send them as json, key-value pairs etc.

Spring framework uses the @ModelAttribute annotation when you wish to map a multipart request to an object.
When you have a normal key-value request, you use the @RequestBody annotation.
Thus, you can't have the MultipartFile optional, because you have to use different annotations. Using two different methods, one per request type, solves the issue. Example,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/withFile", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public ReturnModel updateFile(@ModelAttribute RequestModel rm) {
    // do something.
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/noFile", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = "application/json")
public ReturnModel updateJson(@RequestBody RequestModel rm) {
    // do something else.
}
```