# How to config "CommonsMultipartResolver" in spring4 without xml to upload file

Tags: java, file, spring-mvc, uploading, spring-4

I use xml config spring4 is work well.like this：

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"
    p:defaultEncoding="utf-8" >
    <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->  
    <!-- <property name="maxUploadSize" value="40000000" /> -->  
</bean>
```

when I config spring4 without xml.like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "common.user", "service" })
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringMVCConfig {

@Bean
public ViewResolver createInternalResourceViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setContentType("text/html");
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/view/");
    //viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}

@Bean
public DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler createDefaultServletHttpRequestHandler() {
    return new DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler();
}


@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver createMultipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver=new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
    return resolver;
}
```

}

It throws an exception:

```
 九月 30, 2014 6:01:08 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
严重: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current request is not of type [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest]: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@5ebfad8d] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current request is not of type [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest]: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@5ebfad8d
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:157)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at common.servlet.RootFilter.doFilter(RootFilter.java:71)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

From `MultipartResolver` Javadoc : *To define an implementation, create a bean with the id "multipartResolver" in a DispatcherServlet's application context.*

In your xml configuration, the bean has the correct id of `multipartResolver`, but not in your current java configuration. You should write :

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver=new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
    return resolver;
}
```

or

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver createMultipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver=new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
    return resolver;
}
```

Comment: Seriously ! I lost 2 hours for that ! Why Spring does not take the only bean which is of type CommonsMultipartResolver. And I don't talk about the error message that was saying that my @RequestParam was not present whereas I had my input file with the correct name. Honnestly, Spring could do better there. At least, a meaningful error message. Thank you Serge Ballesta anyway.

Comment: I've done this, yet I keep getting errors about ths content type being not supported. Any idea why [this is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044639/file-upload-wont-work/42044768#42044768)?