# Is Multipart/form-data Content-Type reserved for HTTP POST only?

Tags: http, spring-mvc

I'm trying to do HTTP PATCH with multipart/form-data Content-Type as I'm uploading a file. However, Spring's StandardServletMultipartResolver only considers requests with POST HTTP method. The content type check is done after http method check. Anything other than POST is not considered multipart even when Content-Type is set to multipart.

Is multipart contentType supposed to be used with POST only?

```
public class StandardServletMultipartResolver implements MultipartResolver
    (...)
    public boolean isMultipart(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // Same check as in Commons FileUpload...
        if (!"post".equals(request.getMethod().toLowerCase())) {
            return false;
        }
        String contentType = request.getContentType();
        return (contentType != null && contentType.toLowerCase().startsWith("multipart/"));
    }
```

Comment: Why not override it with a custom resolver like how this person has done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728100/file-upload-via-http-put-request

Comment: @Vasan didn't know it was this simple. Thanks.